# DLL Pinvoke with Windows Mobile C++ libraries porting to C#

Tags: dll, opencv, windows-mobile, pinvoke

I am trying to use OpenCV as [here](http://alexkarpus.com/opencv/), and I am stuck at one moment where I get PInvoke, namely:

my `DLL.cpp`

```
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
//...
DLL_API short processImage(const char* in_file, const char * out_file)
//...
```

my `form.cs`

```
[DllImport("DLL", EntryPoint = "processImage")]
        private static extern short _ProcessImage(byte[] in_file, byte[] out_file);

        public static short binarizeImage(string in_file, string out_file)
        {
            return _ProcessImage(StringToASCIIByteArray(in_file), StringToASCIIByteArray(out_file));
        }

    public static byte[] StringToASCIIByteArray(string str)
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str + "\0");
    }
```

I think that this might be a problem with target architecture (in my VS 2008 project). When I use 'Any CPU' it compiles & runs but throws Pinvoke, when I set it to 'Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I)' it compiles but doesn't want to deploy and I got this in output window:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: DLL, Configuration: Debug Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I) ------
1>The system cannot find the path specified.
1>
2>------ Deploy started: Project: smartDeviceOcr, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Deploying 'D:\VS 2008 Projects\C++\SmartDevice\ocr\smartDeviceOcr\bin\Debug\smartDeviceOcr.exe'
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does the specific ARMV4I matter ? I have ARM920T on my mobile. Can/should I edit this to make it work ?

---

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear the Pinvoke points to :

```
return _ProcessImage(StringToASCIIByteArray(in_file), StringToASCIIByteArray(out_file));
```

and the exception message is :

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled
  Message="Cannot find the library DLL PInvoke 'DLL'."
  StackTrace:
    in smartDeviceOcr.Form1.binarizeImage(String in_file, String out_file)
    in smartDeviceOcr.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    in System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    in System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    in System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
    in System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
    in Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
    in System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
    in smartDeviceOcr.Program.Main()
```

---

**EDIT2:**

Ok now it's really strange. I have changed few things. I have added the openCV's dlls to the deployment list in the project properties so that I can see that they are being copied on deployment and I have copied manually all the dlls to exe directory on the PC.

I have also changed some of the deployment options in DLL project so that the dlls are copied to the proper directory (automatically) on the phone and ....

now I have the error on runtime (when trying to access the function from the dll - opencv) :

> The remote connection to the device has been lost

Comment: OpenCV is native code.  You'll need a version that was built to target your processor.

Comment: This version was built for Windows mobile processors (I use the version from the  site I mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: The pinvoke marshaller appears to disagree.  Seeing the actual exception message would help us help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: I have added the exception text to the answer but I don't think it's that useful.

Comment: It is a simple "file not found" error.  Copy "dll.dll" to the same directory as your managed exe.  Also copy the opencv dlls there.  Pick a better name btw.

Comment: I have done what you suggested and I have added results of these operations in the question. By add the dll.dll to the directory of exe you meant directory on the PC ? I have tried both PC and mobile and nothing ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't see any answers I post my answer (although I still have problems with this)

The problem can be solved by adding directories to which dlls should be deployed to:

`Project-> Properties -> Deployment -> Remote Directory`

and properly specify files in:

`Project-> Properties -> Deployment -> Additional Files`

as like

```
highgui200.dll|$(SolutionDir)\opencv_winmo\dll|%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\smartDeviceOcr|0
cv200.dll|$(SolutionDir)\opencv_winmo\dll|%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\smartDeviceOcr|0
cxcore200.dll|$(SolutionDir)\opencv_winmo\dll|%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\smartDeviceOcr|0
ml200.dll|$(SolutionDir)\opencv_winmo\dll|%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\smartDeviceOcr|0
msvcr90.dll|$(BINDIR)\$(INSTRUCTIONSET)\|%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\smartDeviceOcr|0
```